# Chemfig: colored unshared electron pair

Tags: chemfig

Can I color the unshared electron pair with Chemfig? With this

```
R'-[0]\textcolor{red}{\lewis{2:6:,O}}H
```

The oxygen becomes red, but his unshared electron pair remains in black

Comment: You are more likely to get the answer you are looking for if you include more details. Usually a complete working version starting from `\documentclass` all the way down to `\end{document}` would help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{color}

\setlewis[]{}{}{fill=red, draw=red}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{R'-[0]\textcolor{red}{\lewis{2:6:,O}}H}
\end{document}
```

[image]